# T-SQL iteratively check history pattern

Tags: t-sql, iteration

How do you make a selection based on an item's prior history?

For example, I'm trying to select an item that has a val of 1, previously had a val of 10, and previously before that had a val of 1.  The only itemId that should satisfy the below data would be itemId = 3.

```
    WITH Items (itemId, date, val) AS (
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 
    )
    select distinct itemId from Items where val = 1
    --and a previous date val = 10
    --and a previous previous date val = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the **Value on Prior Date** requirement, you have to use a [ROW_NUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) Ordering by the ItemId and the Date.

Then you do a two **self joins** on Id plus the RowNum joins to the one before it (in effect to the previous date), and add the `WHERE` clauses to 1-10-1

```
WITH Items_Original (itemId, date, val) AS 
(
    SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 
),
Items As
(
    Select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId, Date) AS RowNum, * 
        FROM Items_Original
) 
select * 
from Items I1
    Inner JOIN Items I2
        On I1.itemId = I2.itemId
        And I1.RowNum = I2.RowNum-1
    Inner JOIN Items I3
        On I2.itemId = I3.itemId
        And I2.RowNum = I3.RowNum-1
Where 1=1
    And I1.val = 1
    And I2.val = 10
    And I3.val = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the specific answer you're after.  Not sure how useful it is in an abstract sense, though.  Are you always going to be looking for items that have exactly 3 values, 1-10-1?

```
SELECT
   A.itemID
FROM
   Items A
   INNER JOIN Items B ON A.itemID = B.itemID AND B.val = 10
   INNER JOIN Items C ON B.itemID = C.itemID AND C.val = 1
WHERE
   A.val = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH Items (itemId, date, val) AS (
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '5/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '6/1/2011'), 10 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, CONVERT(datetime, '7/1/2011'), 1 
    ),
cte as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by itemId order by date) [rn]
    from Items t
)

select distinct a.itemId
from cte a
join cte b on b.rn = a.rn + 1 and b.itemId = a.itemId
join cte c on c.rn = b.rn + 1 and c.itemId = a.itemId
where a.val = 1 and b.val = 10 and c.val = 1
```